# How to implement in Python to find two unknown features to cluster the known samples from the rest of the samples?

Tags: python

I have a dataset named:`synthetic_feature_file` with over 50,000 features and 43 samples. Given `sample_indices = syn_data.index.isin([1, 6, 7, 11, 14, 15, 27])`, which represents the indices of known samples, I want to separate them from the rest of the samples and mark them with a different color compared to the other samples. The data of the known samples and the other samples should not overlap. Could someone provide a piece of code to handle this?

Additionally, here is the previous code I wrote. Since it only performs random processing, I want to implement other methods or other way to meet the requirements described in the previous paragraph:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

syn_data = pd.read_csv(synthetic_feature_file)
sample_indices = syn_data.index.isin([1, 6, 7, 11, 14, 15, 27])
x_feature = np.random.choice(syn_data.columns[70:85])
y_feature = np.random.choice(syn_data.columns[30:60])

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
other_samples = syn_data.iloc[~sample_indices]
plt.scatter(other_samples[x_feature], other_samples[y_feature], color='blue', label='Other Samples')
red_samples = syn_data.iloc[sample_indices]
plt.scatter(red_samples[x_feature], red_samples[y_feature], color='red', label='Sample Indices')

plt.xlabel(x_feature)
plt.ylabel(y_feature)
plt.title("Visualization")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and i hope that it can be like in this way:[link](https://img.onl/ZBbht)
image source:[Google](https://medium.com/ai-academy-taiwan/clustering-%E5%88%86%E7%BE%A4%E6%87%B6%E4%BA%BA%E5%8C%85-9c0bb861a3ba)

Comment: My original code produces poorly separated red and blue sample clusters in the generated images each time it runs. Below are the images generated by running the code each time:
[link](https://img.onl/EkyEhN)
[link](https://img.onl/7ZUIwh)

Comment: with the gven data, it would be hard to show clusters becuase the data is actually not clustered.

Comment: @D.L those pic i posted on previous comment were cuz code was  set to randomly select two variables. Is it possible to change this setting and find another method?

Comment: i believe that the `seabourn` module offers good examples of clustered data.  https://pypi.org/project/seaborn

Answer (score 0):

clustering would be unlikely to work with random data (it just would not form clusters).

For this you can use the seaborn package: https://pypi.org/project/seaborn

The penguines dataset is quite a nice demonstration:

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="flipper_length_mm", y="bill_length_mm", hue="species")
```

which gives this:

[image]

Which i believe is what you want.